# Linux: multiple-SIGIO problem (async serial communication)

Tags: linux, asynchronous, serial-port, signals

I'm esperiencing a SIGIO-related problem in a C++ program I'm working on.

- Platform: Linux 2.6.30, x86 Arch
- Scenario: async serial communication.

I followed [this async-communication example](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-Programming-HOWTO/x115.html#AEN144) from the Linux Serial Programming HowTo and it worked flawlessy.

Then I removed the "sleep+check wait_flag" thing and now I handle the read() part directly in signal_handler_IO(). That is, when some input is available, the signal handler is called and it forces a read on the serial port (*).

My code seems to work but unfortunately when new input is available the SIGIO signal is raised several times so I get spurious/incomplete reads (each SIGIO received forces a read).

I changed [VMIN and VTIME](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html) serial options to control the read buffer (i.e. VMIN=255/VTIME=15, VMIN=50/VTIME=0, ...). I tried setting SA_SIGINFO flag (as suggested by some), but no success.

So:

- what am I missing about SIGIO raising/handling?
- is there a way to avoid this "SIGIO storm"?
- is there any way to control SIGIO raising policies?

Thanks in advance.

Bye.

(*): actually I'm following [this C++ FAQ Lite hint](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2) so the signal handler calls a member function of an object that encapsulates all my serial handling stuff. Unfortunately the problem still happens, even if I invoke read() in the signal handler itself.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `read` while in a signal handler? This is bad. Very few functions are [async-signal safe](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SignalSafety). The SIGIO storm might be caused by read sending SIGIO recursively. Your signal handler should just set a flag and return immediately.

Comment: No, the signal handler (as suggested by C++ FAQ Lite) calls a member function of a non-static object that does the actual read().

Anyway I found a simple solution: I've added a buffer (with thread-safe access) for the read bytes. Each time the signal handler is called, I do the read() on serial port and the read bytes are appended to that buffer.

Then the "SIGIO storm" problem is solved because I can extract what I need by reading that buffer when I want.

PS: thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm glad you found a way. To clarify my point about signal-safety: It doesn't matter that you were calling a member function; the top of your stack was still the signal handler.

Comment: You can't call read() in the signal handling context. That is, the signal handler can not call read() nor can anything the signal handler calls.

Comment: You can, in fact, call `read` from a signal handler. See the list of async-signal-safe functions at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html.